# Me dice que la variable no se esta iniciando

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Estoy compilando un programa para clase, que tiene que mostrar de los datos que yo le introduzca el caracol ganador.

```
program Entregable2;
type    //Definir tipos de datos
    tiempo = record
        h       : 0..23;
        m       : 0..59;
    end;
    participante = record
        nombre      :string;
        dorsal      : 1..4;
        hora        :tiempo;
        duracion    :tiempo;
        velocidad   :real
    end;

var     //Declaracion de variables
    Caracol: array [1..4] of Participante;
    i: integer;
    Salida:tiempo;


procedure vel(HoraS,MinS,HoraLl,MinLl :integer; var Caracol:Participante ) ; //Calcular la velocidad del caracol
begin
    if MinS>MinLl then 
        begin 
            MinLl:=MinLl+60;
            HoraLl:=HoraLl-1
        end;
    Caracol.duracion.m:= MinLl-MinS;
    if HoraS>HoraLl then HoraLl:=HoraLl+24;
    Caracol.duracion.h:= HoraLl-HoraS;
    Caracol.velocidad:= 50/(Caracol.duracion.h*60+Caracol.duracion.m);
end;
procedure Iden(sal:tiempo;Caracol:participante);    //Identificar participante
begin
    writeln('Introduce el nombre');
    readln(Caracol.nombre);
    writeln('Introduce el dorsal');
    readln(Caracol.dorsal);
    writeln('Introduce la hora a la que ha llegado, y después los minutos');
    readln(Caracol.hora.h);
    readln(Caracol.hora.m);
    vel(sal.h,sal.m,Caracol.hora.h,Caracol.hora.m,Caracol);

end;
procedure Ganador(Caracol:array of Participante); //Identificar ganador
var 
i: integer;
a: integer;
b: integer;
    begin
        for i:=1 to 4 do
        begin
            if i=1 then 
            begin
                a:=Caracol[i].duracion.h*60+Caracol[i].duracion.m;
                b:=i
            end
            else
            begin
                if a>(Caracol[i].duracion.h*60+Caracol[i].duracion.m) then 
                begin 
                    a:=Caracol[i].duracion.h*60+Caracol[i].duracion.m; 
                    b:=i;
                end;
            end;
        end;
        writeln('El caracol ganador es el número ', b,', que ha tardado un total de ', caracol[b].duracion.h,' horas y ', caracol[b].duracion.m, ' minutos, a una velocidad de ' ,caracol[b].velocidad:4:4, ' cm/m.');
    end;

begin   //Inicio del programa
    writeln('Introduce la hora de salida, y después los minutos');
    readln(Salida.h);
    readln(Salida.m);
    for i:=1 to 4 do
    begin
        Iden(salida, Caracol[i]);
    end;
    Ganador(Caracol);
end.
```

Esta es la linea donde me da el **Error**.

```
Iden(salida, Caracol[i]);
```

Y me dice que la variable Caracol no se esta iniciando. Gracias!

Comment: No recuerdo mucho pascal.. pero no tenes que inicializar el vector Caracol? ahi solo lo estas declarando...

Comment: @Luis Daniel: Gracias por querer editar y mejorar las preguntas, pero trata de limitarte a cambios significativos para no llenar la cola de revisiones con cambios triviales. Gracias.

Comment: Esta bien gracias por el dato lo voy a tomar en cuenta para ayudar de verdad a la comunidad